# nullPointerException at getMarshaller().marshal() method in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
import com.something.model.StudentModel;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {

    private Marshaller marshaller;

    @Autowired
    StudentDao dao;

    @Override
    public StringWriter getStudentObjects() throws JAXBException {
        List<StudentModel> sm = dao.getStudentData();

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
//        String result="";
//        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(StudentModel.class);
        for (StudentModel studentModel: sm) {
            StudentModel studentModel1 = new StudentModel();
            studentModel1.setName(studentModel.getName());
            System.out.println(studentModel.getName());
            studentModel1.setStu_Id(studentModel.getStu_Id());
            studentModel1.setClass_Id(studentModel.getClass_Id());
            studentModel1.setAddress(studentModel.getAddress());
            studentModel1.setAge(studentModel.getAge());
//            Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
//            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
//            set
            System.out.println(studentModel1.toString());
//            getMarshaller().marshal(studentModel1,new StreamResult(sw));
//            result = sw.toString();
            getMarshaller().marshal(studentModel1, new StreamResult(sw));
            System.out.println("............,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,...................");
//            System.out.println(result);
            sw.toString();
        }
        return sw;
    }

//    getter and setter for marshalling

    public Marshaller getMarshaller() {
        return marshaller;
    }

    public void setMarshaller(Marshaller marshaller) {
        this.marshaller = marshaller;
    }

}
```

The above code is to marshall the list of javaObjects. I am able to get the list of data and set it to the **StudentModelClass** to marshall the objects. However i am getting a nullpointerException at `getMarshaller().marshal(studentModel1, new StreamResult(sw));` method. Any ideas how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: I think you haven't set the marshaller in the code. You are creating Marshaller m from context. Without initializing marshaller variable you are getting it. That's why marshaller variable is null. Use Autowire or setter to set it first

Comment: Hi @HarshMishra thank you. it helped me.